# LAN data transfers slower than internet downloads

Tags: networking, windows-10, ubuntu, samba

I am aware of similar questions. However my setup is different:

- **Source**: Windows 10 machine connected to router via LAN cable with Intel Ethernet connection i219-lm. Hosting files via network share.
- **Destination**: Ubuntu 18.04 laptop with some <s>54Mbps</s> Wi-Fi Card (Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n) with `$samba --version: Version 4.7.6-Ubuntu`
- **Router**: FritzBox 6340

I can easily download files to my Ubuntu laptop at around 5-6 MB/s. However if I want to copy files from the Windows machine via some Samba share to my laptop I can maximally reach 2-3 MB/s. Why is that? What might be wrong?

Comment: What version of SMB are you using?  Please edit your question with the necessary relevant information required to answer your question.

Comment: 5-6 MebiBytes per second is way faster than 802.11a or 802.11g (54Megabit/sec Wi-Fi) ever went, even with proprietary frame bursting schemes. Can you figure out the exact chipset of your Ubuntu laptop's Wi-Fi card, or if it's a well-known card, the make and model of the card? Can you post a screenshot of an Ookla Speedtest.net run from the Ubuntu laptop, showing greater than 30 Megabits/sec? 2-3 MebiBytes/sec is actually typical for 802.11g or 802.11a 54 Megabit/sec Wi-Fi. It would also be helpful to know the exact make and model of your Wi-Fi AP (wireless router).

Comment: I can't post a screenshot of the Ookla Speedtest right now, since I don't want to interrupt the file transfer. But I remeber that the speedtest showed something around 45-50 Mbps > 30 Mbps. My fritzbox is showing that I my Ubuntu laptop is connected  with 65 Mbit/s